# How to modify logstash in order to send failed message to SQS DLQ

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-sqs

I am trying to modify Logstash 7.6 in order to send failed messages to a SQS DLQ [1]. Specifically, I need this modification when Logstash uses a SQS input plugin and elasticsearch output plugin. I do not use nothing in filter part. That is, I have two queues a main queue and its SQS DLQ. The file I am trying to modify is [2]. Only to see if this work I am trying to add an abort after line 325, but the SQS DLQ associated to the main SQS not received any message. Could you give some advice, please?

[1] https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/8804933e2b15d867a049319e52ee61223552b6be/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

PDTA: I know that logstash has its own dlq but I want a SQS DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

you would want to modify the [DLQ write](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/8804933e2b15d867a049319e52ee61223552b6be/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb#L343) operation to do your own logic.

where `action` is an [ES specific tuple](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/8804933e2b15d867a049319e52ee61223552b6be/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb#L121) e.g. `['update', { ... }, event]` - `action[2]` gets you the original Logstash event.